# Get pymysql.connect cursor.execute() chunks in Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pymysql, chunks

I Have this code:

```
with DATAB.connect().execution_options(autocommit=True) as DB:
    with DB.begin():
        DataContainer = []
        for chunk in pd.read_sql_query("SELECT id, plat_id FROM plats WHERE date_request >= '{}';".format(Previous_Date), con=DB, chunksize=10000):
            DataContainer.append(chunk)
            del chunk
            gc.collect()
        DataFrame = pd.concat(DataContainer, ignore_index=True)
    DB.close()
DATAB.dispose()
```

I want to get the chunks from the SQL query as I did in the code above using pymysql:

```
Conn = pymysql.connect(user=Config[0], password=Config[1], host=Config[2], database=Config[3], charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
with Conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute() ??????
    cursor.close() 
Conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can paginate like this;

```
query = "select * from table order by id limit %d offset %d" % (chunksize, offset)
result_rows = cursor.execute(query)
```

Put in a loop and increase `offset` by `chunkSize` every iteration.